# Grub консоль после перезапуска ОС

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grub

У меня стоял 1 ссд на ноуте, на нем win 11
Вчера поставил 2ой ссд и накатил Ubuntu на него

После перезагрузки ОС открывается граб консоль, но не граб меню

Заметил такую закономерность, если после перезапуска ОС зайти в биос и сохраниться без изменений, то загрузится граб меню, где я могу выбрать ОС

Вот и вопрос, как сделать так, чтобы после перезагрузки ОС выкидывало в граб меню, а не в консоль?